# Go get access to Users Resources, Policies and Permissions in Keycloak 7.x

Tags: keycloak

I am evaluating Keycloak 7.X to be used in our applications consist of approximately twelve microservices (Spring Boot)  and four Angular 6.x applications. I plan to use Keycloak adapters for Angular applications as well as Spring Boot instead of OAuth 2.0 for SpringBoot. My proof of concept must demonstrate the following use cases.

(1) Single Sign-On. 
(2) Role-Based access control
(3) Policy and Permission- e.g. a user with role "Supervisor" should be able to access the salary of all employees of the organization. However, he/she could give raise to only those employees who work at the same location of the supervisor. In other words, there will an attribute "location" assoicated with each user. Even if the role of the user is "Supervisor", the permssion must consider the attribute "location" to determine access to the resource.

I am planning to use JWT. The JWT will contain the list of permissions and the individual microservice will determine using the combination of "location" and "permission".

Unfortunately, I am unable to configure the client in Keycloak to assign policies and Permissions nor could I find any example on internet.

Answer (score 0):

To use policies and permissions your applications should implement [User-Manager Access 2.0 protocol](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/oauth-uma-grant-2.0-09.html). Read [User-Managed Access](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_user_managed_access) documentation page for example flow.

> I am planning to use JWT. The JWT will contain the list of permissions and the individual microservice will determine using the combination of "location" and "permission".

If the logic behind access definition is located in microservices then you don't need policies and permissions. You can just define roles (e.g. supervisor) and attributes (e.g. location) on Keycloak side and set them to be included in access token (JWT).

Comment: Thank you Vadim. I will check it out.

Comment: The link to User-Managed Access page was incorrect, I updated it.